# Flutter: Streambuilder for documents from query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How do I get a listview of all the items returned from query snapshot?

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("children")
        .where("parentUID", isEqualTo: uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((result) {
      result.docs.forEach((result) {
        setState(() {
          childFirstName = result["childFirstName"];
          childLastName = result["childLastName"];
          points = result["points"];
          docID = result.id;
          print('$docID');
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

This is all I could come up with, here is an image of the database,
[Image of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wydxn.png)

How can I make a listview which creates an item for every document which the `parentUID` is equal to the current users `uid` which is already stored in a variable `uid`

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared? If you're uncertain how to show those docs in a list view, have a look at this documenaiton: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes

Comment: I dont know where to start

Comment: I want to create a query and make a stream out of the results, make a listview and each result into an item

Comment: That's exactly what the shows how to do. It creates a `_usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots()`, which you can replace with your query, and then uses that in a `StreamBuilder`. Did you *try* making that example work in your own code?

Comment: I dont want a stream of all the documents in the collection, but the documents in the collection ```children``` that have a ```parentUID``` which matches (equalto) the current users id, which I stored in a variable called uid

Comment: As said: you can put your query in the same place as the `_usersStream` in that example. Try it, and you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sample code below.
It shows how to use the stream from your query and return a `ListView.builder` which displays the information in a `ListTile`.

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('children')
    .where('parentUID', isEqualTo: uid)
    .snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data == null) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
      final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> docs = snapshot.data!.docs;

      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          final doc = docs[index];
          final childFirstName = doc["childFirstName"];
          final childLastName = doc["childLastName"];
          final points = doc["points"];
          final docID = doc.id;

          return ListTile(
            title: Text('$childFirstName $childLastName'),
            subtitle: Text(points),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  },
)
```