# How to refresh the screen after deleting a document?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on flutter app which will delete a document after clicking on delete button. To delete a document, I have defined the following function:

```
Future<void> deleteEvent(String eventId) async {
events
    .doc(eventId)
    .delete()
    .then((value) => print("Event Deleted"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to delete Event: $error"));
}
```

I am calling this function whenever the delete button is pressed as follows:

```
 ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {
     deleteEvent(widget.eventId);
     },
     child: Padding(
     padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
     child: Text('Delete'),
     ),
```

This is working fine. However, I want to refresh the screen as soon as the event is deleted. So that deleted event disappears from the screen after pressing the delete button. I have tried to use `setState()` method also:

```
Future<void> deleteEvent(String eventId) async {
setState(() {
  events
    .doc(eventId)
    .delete()
    .then((value) => print("Event Deleted"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to delete Event: $error"));
  });
}
```

Still not able to achieve what I want to.

**Update:**

I am looking for a simpler alternative. Just a simple code or function that will refresh/reload the screen as soon as the delete function is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stream builder to get documents so it will get updated asynchronously

Take a look at. [How to add stream builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68877842/flutter-streambuilder-for-documents-from-query)

Answer (score 1):

After your deleteEvent() function call in the onTap, you can call setState like this: `setState(()=>{});`

Comment: I have tried this. Still it's not working.

Comment: maybe it is because you don't await it. Can you try:
```onPressed: () async {
     await deleteEvent(widget.eventId);
     setState(()=>{});
     }```

Comment: No still it's not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

SetState doesn't work because the delete function is async. setState is synchronous. Use s stream for the documents with a StreamBuilder instead that will automatically refresh or put a setState inside the .then() of your existing code and inside the setState repopulate the data in the widget after you await the data like this:

```
Future<void> deleteEvent(String eventId) async {
  events
    .doc(eventId)
    .delete()
    .then((value) => {
      //final List documents = await make call to firebase for documents
      //setState({
      //update the UI with the above documents
    })
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to delete Event: $error"));
}
```

Comment: I am looking for an simpler alternative. Just a simple function or code that will refresh the screen as soon as document is deleted.

Comment: You probably need a StreamBuilder. There might be a better way, but reality is it can only be so simple. I can't give you a shortcut or do it for you. The computer can't read minds. It is annoying, but it is also reality.

Answer (score 0):

define a bool (deleting) with initial value of false, then inside onPressed make it true, and use Future.delayed after calling your function and then call (setState) inside it and make your boolean again false inside setState function. while (deleting) is true you can show CircularProgressIndicator() widget:

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                deleting = true;
              })
              deleteEvent(widget.eventId).then((value) {
                Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) (
                  setState(() {
                    deleting = false;
                  })
                ));
              });
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: Text('Delete'),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but it's not working. Maybe I am missing something. I don't know.